# Asp.Net MVC 3 - Duplicate JS Files for PartialView (Ajax)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

In my _MainLayout (parentlayout), i have referenced several JS-files.

Partialviews are added to a div using the following javascript/jquery functions:

```
    $.ajax(link, {
            dataType: "html",
            cache: false,
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                return pageDownloaded(data, a);
            },
            complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
            //add .on event
            }
        });
```

and

```
   function pageDownloaded(data, anchor){
var link = anchor.attr("href").replace(/^\#/, ""),
title = anchor.attr("title"),
id = link.replace(/[\/\.]/,"-"),
target = "#main-content",
div = $('<div style="left: 100%" id="'+id+'">'+data+'</div>').appendTo($(target));
$("#wrapper > section > section > header h1").html(title);

if ($('#wrapper > section > section').css('position')=='absolute') {
    $("> div:last", target).css({left: 0, position: 'relative'}).siblings().remove();
    $('#wrapper > section > section').show().animate({left: 0}, 300, "easeInOutQuart",                                       function(){$(this).css('left',0);});
} else {
 /* $("> div", target).animate({left: "-=100%"}, "slow", "easeInOutQuart", function(){
        $(this).css('left',0);
        $("> div:last", target).css({position: 'relative'}).siblings().remove();
    });*/
    $("> div", target).animate({ left: "-=100%" },500, function () {
        $(this).css('left', 0);
        $("> div:last", target).css({ position: 'relative' }).siblings().remove();
    });

}

 $(window).trigger('drilldown');
 }
```

Problem is, if i set this in a JS File loaded by my masterpage
(default actions to be added to every page (dateinput, ...))

```
  (function($){
    $.fn.placeholder = function(options) {
      return this.each(function() {
        if ( !("placeholder"  in document.createElement(this.tagName.toLowerCase()))) {
          var $this = $(this);
          var placeholder = $this.attr('placeholder');
          $this.val(placeholder).data('color', $this.css('color')).css('color', '#aaa');
          $this
            .focus(function(){ if ($.trim($this.val())===placeholder){       $this.val('').css('color', $this.data('color'))} })
            .blur(function(){ if (!$.trim($this.val())){       $this.val(placeholder).data('color', $this.css('color')).css('color', '#aaa'); } });
        }
      });
    };
  })(jQuery);

  $(document).ready(function() {
      $('input[placeholder]', target).placeholder();

      $("input[type=date]", target).dateinput();

      $("input:checkbox,input:radio,select,input:file", target).uniform();

  });
```

I have to reference it again in my PartialView.
I also have to reference the jquery.min.js files again, ...

How can i solve this duplication problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is a confusing and fairly messy question, maybe this will help you straighten out your code.

Following that, content pages can be loaded that should **not** contain on_load type activity or additional global script references.

1. Load `MasterPage` (Script references, CSS references, etc)
2. Load `Content` (Partial Views, dynamic data, specific scripts, etc)
3. Content finished loading? Run `Content.Init()` type functions.  (Ex. `MyView.GetData()`)
4. User interaction begins.

Comment: That wouldn't be possible, because i'm using the hashcange jquery plugin. This allows me to load the partialview on document ready and allows my guest to bookmark the url and be redirected to the right page :). 
Additional advice?